# OrBac or ROBAC or MultiOrg-RBAC with OAuth2/OpenId

Tags: authorization, access-control, rbac, katana, abac

I work for an organization that hosts applications used by many other organizations that reside in a hierarchy (I work in the education field).
[This](http://www.profsandhu.com/confrnc/misconf/robac06.pdf) article detailing what they call "ROBAC" identifies and proposes a new model for access control that we'd like to try and implement. Does anyone have experience with implementing IdentityServer by Thinktecture or any other .NET/Katana based technology?

Is it possible to use OAUTH2/OpenId to implement a ROBAC/OrBac model? If so, is there any documentation available out there on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is ABAC, attribute-based access control and possibly XACML, the extensible access control markup language which implements ABAC.

ABAC is generic enough to implement RBAC, ROBAC, and generally *-bac. In ABAC you get to define the attributes you need. Those attributes can be about:

- the user e.g. role, department, age, clearance...
- the object (resource) they're trying to access e.g document, classification, owner, author, status...
- the action they want to do on that object e.g. view, delete, approve...
- the context e.g. time of day.

You then combine these attributes into policies e.g.

*A user with the role publisher can do the action publish on a document if the document status is draft and if the user's department is equal to the document's department*

There are a lot of resources on ABAC/XACML. Check out:

- the NIST project page on ABAC
- the OASIS XACML standard page
- the Axiomatics Policy Server Express Edition - a lightweight implementation of ABAC.